# I cannot execute docformer(config) function written in the read.md file from https://github.com/cregouby/docformer

Tags: r, forms, github

I want to extract text from image using the code in https://github.com/cregouby/docformer, but when I executed the code written in the read.me file, an error: could not find function "docformer" has occured. I had installed and imported all libraries written in DESCRIPTION file, but I couldn't fix the error

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kkfz.jpg)

I checked if docformer library includes docformer function by running the code "ls("package:docformer")" on R, but docformer function is not displayed.